# How do I convert JMS binary stream to .NET/C# types?

Tags: .net, jms

I have Java code that sends a `MyClass` object instance to JMS:

```java
MyClass mc = new MyClass("str1", 12345, "");

JmsTemplate tpl = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
tpl.setReceiveTimeout(2000);
tpl.send("...", session -> {
        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
        message.setObject(mc);
        message.setJMSCorrelationID("22");
        return message;
});
```

MyClass is some Java class with properties:

```java
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    String path1;
    int path2;
    String path3;
    public MyClass(String path1, int path2, String path3)
    {
        this.path1 = path1;
        this.path2 = path2;
        this.path3 = path3;
    }
}
```

Now I have binary stream of MyClass instance in .NET/C# client. How can I deserialize it to .NET type like:

```cs
class MyClass {
    public string Path1 { get; set; }
    public int Path2 { get; set; }
    public string Path3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of work & pain when you can just avoid JMS `ObjectMessage` and use a sensible data format which is easily consumed across different languages and platforms (e.g. JSON, XML, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing serialized Java objects with .NET code is not something you should really spend time trying to implemented and hopefully test as there are already plenty of good solutions to such problems like using JSON serialized objects etc protobuf etc.  Using a TextMessage for JSON or a BytesMessage for some protobuf impl etc is going to be a much faster route to something that works and is easily testable.

The JMS ObjectMessage should be avoided in almost every case as it poses potential security risks that have forced JMS providers to lock down what can and cannot be passed to it so just from that perspective I'd advise against its use.